# Facebook only one user permission window

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I am creating user login to my web app and I have problem with dialog window. I am using JavaScript API. In normal application login show just one dialog window with all permisions, but  my application shows 3 windows. One for each permission.

Is there some way how to put it to one window?
Or can you tell me what I am doing wrong??

```
FB.init({
      appId  : facebook_key,
      status : true, // check login status
      cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
});
FB.login(function(response) {

}, (scope: 'publish_stream,status_update,manage_pages'});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, this isn't possible.

For more details and best practices, you can check this documentation by facebook : [Permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/)